# referencing csv file VS. locating it into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a website im working on for a car dealership. There inventory is being sent over to me via FTP CSV file, once a day everyday (right now). My question is is it better in insert this info into a MYSQL db or leave it in a CSV file.

All content on this site will come from this file including pictures and video. I have a feeling that it will be better from a security stand point and a speed stand point as well.

Thank you for your input!

Comment: This is not a good question for SO, what's the programming problem? Nevertheless I don't see how pictures and videos can be stored in a CSV? Normally you would store data in a database, for easy access, and pictures and videos as files, perhaps with references to their location and content in the database.

Comment: CSV files are useful for transfering data between sites, they're lousy for direct access in applications. Definitely use a database.

Comment: Thank you I am storing video and pictures in db via a direct link. (Thought that went with out saying) and thank you for explaining why MySQL would be better then CSV that is what I was thinking just wanted to double check have a good Christmas everyone!!!